# Lxml tree returns xpath expressions as a string when given like the following example

Tags: python-3.x, xpath, xml-parsing, lxml

```
import lxml.etree as LX

url= "https://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"

response = requests.get(url)
xml_string = LX.fromstring(response.content)
path='"//*[1.1.1]"'
result = xml_string.xpath(path)
print(result)
```

The result of the above code returns the xpath as string itself and doesn't through an error for an invalid xpath

Answer (score 1):

`'"//*[1.1.1]"'` is not an XPath<sup>(*)</sup>. It's a string. Note the quote placement.

An XPath expression that contains nothing but a string will return that string, that's not awfully surprising.

```
import lxml.etree as LX
import requests

url = "https://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/"
response = requests.get(url)

tree = LX.fromstring(response.content)
path = '"Look at me I\'m a string!"'
result = tree.xpath(path)
print(result)
```

prints

```
Look at me I'm a string!
```

---

<sup>(*)</sup> Nitpicking technical point. Of course it is an XPath expression.  If it were not, you would get an error from lxml. It's just not one that selects any elements.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification but is there any way where i can prompt the user that it is an invalid xpath?

Comment: @Jimisaac it's not invalid, otherwise you would get an error. You can prompt the user when the expression returned no elements, if that's what you expect.